# Use Handlebars to generate CSS?

Tags: css, handlebars.js

I'm wondering if Handlebars can be used like Liquid, to precompile and generate dynamic CSS based on variables. I have tried the following code, and it correctly outputs CSS, but as Handlebars is mainly targetted, is there any drawbacks for this?

```
var template = Handlebars.compile("p + p { border-color: {{ borderColor }} }");

var context = {borderColor: "#ffffff"};
var html = template(context);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: You could use something specifically targetted to CSS, like Sass/LESS/Stylus/etc. but there’s nothing really wrong with this, no. (Although you can always `template.replace(/{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}/g, function(_, n) { return context[n]; });` if simple variables are all you need.)

Comment: Thanks, it seems interesting.

Comment: Blender > I'm just thinking about it. Imagine you want a theme builder, you may want to compile a CSS file based on dynamic variables (like Shopify for instance).